# Passing form values through AJAX to php

Tags: php, jquery, post, radio-button

I'm having some real trouble getting this form to send through Ajax. I started off getting the values to send through but came to a stop once the radio button `var messagetype` was added. Since adding the variable the page no longer passes any of the values through where as before it would pass them.

I believe it has something to do with the `var dataString` and the values are not passing through properly, and as it started to go wrong since added `var messagetype` it must have started from here.

I've played around with the code for `var messagetype` by adding a class and trying that, writing it a few ways but still to no avail.

Here's my code:

`js`

```
$('#formsend').click(function(){

var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
//Where I think it's going wrong:
var messagetype = $("input[name='messagetype']:checked").val();

var trackurl = $("input#trackurl").val();
var trackdesc = $("input#trackdesc").val();

var eventdate = $("input#eventdate").val();
var eventdesc = $("input#eventdesc").val();
var adrsone = $("input#adrsone").val();
var adrstwo = $("input#adrstwo").val();
var adrsthree = $("input#adrsthree").val();
var pcode = $("input#pcode").val();

var detail = $("input#subject").val();
var note = $("input#note").val();


  var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone +'&messagetype=' + messagetype + '&trackurl=' + trackurl + '&trackdesc=' + trackdesc + '&eventdate=' + eventdate + '&eventdesc=' + eventdesc + '&adrsone=' + adrsone + '&adrstwo=' + adrstwo + '&adrsthree=' + adrsthree + '&pcode=' + pcode + '&detail=' + detail + '&note=' + note;


$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "processmail.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
    .append("<p>Thank you for contacting me, I will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500);
  }
});
return false;

}); //end form ajax
```

`processmail.php`

```
<?php
$name=sanitiseString($_POST['name']);
$email=sanitiseString($_POST['email']);
$phone=sanitiseString($_POST['phone']);

$messagetype=sanitiseString($_POST['messagetype']);

$trackurl=sanitiseString($_POST['trackurl']);
$trackdesc=sanitiseString($_POST['trackdesc']);

$eventdate=sanitiseString($_POST['eventdate']);
$eventdesc=sanitiseString($_POST['eventdesc']);
$adrsone=sanitiseString($_POST['adrsone']);
$adrstwo=sanitiseString($_POST['adrstwo']);
$adrsthree=sanitiseString($_POST['adrsthree']);
$pcode=sanitiseString($_POST['pcode']);

$detail=sanitiseString($_POST['detail']);
$note=sanitiseString($_POST['note']);

$to='emailme@myemail.com';
$subject='Message from Form: '.$messagetype;
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .='From: '.$name;
$headers .='Reply-To: '.$email;

if($messagetype == 'track'){
$message='<table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Track Description: </td><td>'.$trackdesc.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Track Link: </td><td>'.$trackurl.'</td></tr>
        <table>';

}
elseif($messagetype == 'event'){
$message='<table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Event Description: </td><td>'.$eventdesc.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Event Date: </td><td>'.$eventdate.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Location: </td><td>'.$adrsone.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'.$adrstwo.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'.$adrsthree.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>'.$pcode.'</td></tr>
        <table>';

}
elseif($messagetype == 'message'){
$message='<table>
        <tr><td>Name: </td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Subject: </td><td>'.$detail.'</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message: </td><td>'.$note.'</td></tr>
        <table>';

}

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



function sanitiseString($var)
{
$var = stripslashes($var);
$var = htmlentities($var);
$var = strip_tags($var);
return $var;    
}
?>
```

I am new to this and have followed a few tutorials to achieve it so am now a little stuck as to why it won't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use object for data param.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "processmail.php",
  data: {'name': name, 
        'email': email},
  success: function() {
    $('#form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Message Submitted.</h2>")
    .append("<p>Thank you for contacting me, I will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500);
  }
});
```

Comment: I've opted for this answer as I'm a novice and it worked fine. It's working now thanks. The problem I now have is passing the textarea fields through, I've changed the code from `input#eventdesc` to `textarea#eventdesc` but still not passing the variable through?

Answer (score 3):

use `serialize() or SerializeArray`

```
var dataString = $('#FORMID').serialize();
```

and pass `dataString` to your data variable in `$.ajax` in `data`

**& in php Section** you can get all values of fields present inside form

using `GET or POST` method

`messagetype`  set **hidden field** in your form or append it to `dataString` so you will get messagetype in your php file